# Is it possible to mount one H.D.D. via USB Hub on two PCs?

Tags: linux, mount, usb

Having a HDD Drive on a USB hub with two partitions. Can I mount first partition to Computer A and second partition to Computer B without trouble?

Or even better, would it be possible to mount one partition to both computers?

Comment: It is unclear to me if you think there is a problem sharing a HDD that is connected to PC via a USB hub via some means (not a problem in principle, but I always recommend direct connection for USB-drives) or that you somehow have a hub and/or cables that you can connect to two PCs at the same time.

Comment: I'm having that 7 port USB Hub already. I am looking for a solution to move data from one PC to another. Both PCs are freaking slow (Raspberry Pi approx. 600 bogomips / 100mbs eth with approx. 5mb/s) the fastest solution would be having both Pi's writing to the same storage...

Comment: Effective USB 2.0 is faster than Fast Ethernet but not by an order of magnitude (35MB/s vs 10MB/s IIRC), can't you make one of the Raspberrys into a USB slave?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/q/696951/151431). I am flagging your [su] post for deletion.

Comment: You may have a 7 port hub but it can only connect to one upstream *host*; that port should be labelled and/or use a different style connector.  Do not connect one of the regular ports to a PC's USB port!

Answer (score 5):

USB-protocol deny dual-homing, so only one root device (host) is on a top of hierarcy.
If you want to share partitions - mount them to the one host and then share via smb/nfs/etc.

Comment: Thanks! Since the Computers having only 100mbit, is there a protocol to do a share similar like NFS or Samba but via USB (2.0) which would be faster?

Comment: AFAIR not every PC can be connected via USB. They both should be equipped by special USB-controllers that can act as USB-root and USB-node. Most controllers PC supplied with can act only as USB-root. May be upgrade to 1Gbit NICs is the easiest way around.

Comment: As far subject hosts are RPi's, NIC replacement is not an option. Therefore you should look for some NAS providing iSCSI storage. Also try `BerryBoot Loader` that allow RPi to mount root partition over network.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the different partitions on different computers and/or mount the same partition on two computers.

What you need to do is connect the harddrive to one computer using USB and connect the computers with each other using their network cards (easy via a hub/switch, but with a cross-over cable you can also do this directly).
Then export the partitions via NFS to the other computer

Comment: Zelda can you give specifics how you set it up? (OS / Filesystem / 2 or 1 Partition/s) thanks

Comment: What OS do you run on your PCs?

Comment: Raspbian which is a Debian port, and (not sure yet) Raspbmc, openelec or RasPlex which is some sort of linux-flavor